# Error at compiling example from the Manual tikz-network

Tags: color, packages, csv, xkeyval, edge

As per example on page 26 of the manual  https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/ when doing latexmk -pdflua -pvc or latexmk -pdfxe -pvc I get the following error below. Note: already tried https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/issues/5:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `R' undefined in families `vertex'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \Vertices[RGB]{data/vertices_RGB.csv}

?
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertices[RGB]{data/vertices_RGB.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: As @sebastiano requested here is the link to edges.csv https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/blob/master/doc/data/edges.csv used for my MWE.

Comment: Is it possible that you can add data/vertices_RGB.csv? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have edited the issue by placing at the end the link to the file I used for the edges.csv settings.

Comment: Just observe that the `data/vertices_RGB.csv` file should be replaced by `edges.csv` (or vice-versa).

Comment: @Sigur , got the following error replacing vertices_RGB.csv with edges.csv https://imgur.com/fL0IWlm .

Comment: Just to bring others up to speed: Diego made a bug report at https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/issues/12. I tried in Overleaf with TL17 where it works, and TL19 where it fails, I'm guessing some recent change in a package broke this.

Comment: Grateful for the observation @Torbjøn, I hope that over time this can be resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem are the spaces in the header. Due to a change in etoolbox (it uses \ifstrempty instead of \ifblank internally in a command), datatool is more picky here now. If you change the header in the data-file to

```
 id,x,y,size,color,opacity,label,R,G,B
```

it compiles again. The problematic spaces are the one *after* the R, G, B. That the definition is the problem can be tested by switching it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%old, ",R ," works
%\def\etb@ifdefempty #1{\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \ifblank \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter {\expandafter \strip@prefix \meaning #1}}
%new, ",R ," fails
%\def\etb@ifdefempty #1{\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \ifstrempty \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter {\expandafter \strip@prefix \meaning #1}}


\usepackage{tikz-network}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertices[RGB]{test-vertices.csv} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the datafile with a space:

```
id,x,y,size,color,opacity,label,R ,G,B
 A, 0,  0, .4 , green,  .9   ,  a  ,255,  0,  0
 B, 1, .7, .6 ,      ,  .5   ,  b  ,  0,255,  0
 C, 2,  1, .8 ,orange,  .3   ,  c  ,  0,  0,255
 D, 2,  0, .5 ,   red,  .7   ,  d  , 10,120,255
 E,.2,1.5, .5 ,  gray,       ,  e  , 76, 55,255
```

### Edit

You can try the following patch: (a similar patch is probaly also needed for @@edges and perhaps more commands, so it should be better done by the package author).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\vertex@trim@spacesN\tl_trim_spaces:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd\@@vertices{\DTLifeq}{\vertex@trim@spacesN\dtlkey\DTLifeq}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertices[RGB]{test-vertices.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really, @Ulrike Fisher, the spacing in the header was the central detail. Grateful to you and everyone who helped me..

Comment: I added a possible patch.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah Thank you, sincerely for your collaboration for edit your question. Thanks to Ulrike Fischer to give you an answer. My best regards everyone.